# How to reduce the width of the Master View in a UISplitViewCotroller

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How to reduce the width of the Master View in a UISplitViewCotroller.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the sizing of that control is fixed.  An alternate implementation that is user sizable is [MTSplitViewController](https://github.com/Krumelur/MTSplitViewController)